# while i cloning a private github repository to jenkins through pipeline script i am facing the below error

Tags: git, jenkins, github

Warning: CredentialId "2ea2d11959b1e3fb440067511e560679e7dbc801" could not be found.

> /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/hk4390/private.git # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/hk4390/private.git
>   /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
>   /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress -- https://github.com/hk4390/private.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin

Comment: Please add more details here.

Comment: this is the actual code i run in pipeline script                              
 "stage('checkout') 
           {
       steps
    {
                  git credentialsId: '2ea2d11959b1e3fb440067511e560679e7dbc801', url: 'https://github.com/hk4390/private.git', branch: 'master'
                 }"

Comment: @Hemanth The credential IDs in Jenkins usually contain hyphens as `2ea2d119-59b1-e3fb-4400-67511e560679e7dbc801`. Please verify if this is the cause.